# Trigger for loop and SOQL limits

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, query, limits

I have a trigger. It inserts imported Gears with correct fields' values. One of valu I took from `Detail__c` - related to `MoreInfo__c` object. And `Tool__c` is related to `MoreInfo__c` too. Each `MoreInfo__c` has only one `Detail__c` record, but can have many `Tool__c` records.

And if it's an import of many records I get an error becouse SOQL Limit is 101 records:

```
trigger GearCreationTrigger on Tool__c (after insert) { 
List<Gear__c> toInsert = new List<Gear__c>();

for(Tool__c tool : Trigger.new){
    List<Detail__c> details = [SELECT Info__c FROM Detail__c
                                WHERE MoreInfo__c =: tool.MoreInfo__c LIMIT 1];

    Gear__c gear = new Gear__c(Tool__c = tool.Id);      
    if(details.size() > 0){
        gear.Info__c = details[0].Info__c;
    }
    toInsert.add(gear);
}
if(toInsert.size() > 0) insert toInsert;
}
```

Then I fixed it and now I have this thing:

```
trigger GearCreationTrigger on Tool__c (after insert) { 
List<Gear__c> toInsert = new List<Gear__c>();
List<String> moreInfo = new List<String>();
List<Detail__c> details = [SELECT Info__c FROM Detail__c
                                WHERE MoreInfo__c IN : moreInfo LIMIT 1];

for(Tool__c tool : Trigger.new){
    moreInfo.add(tool.MoreInfo__c);

    Gear__c gear = new Gear__c(Tool__c = tool.Id);      
    if(details.size() > 0){
        gear.Info__c = details[0].Info__c;
    }
    toInsert.add(gear);
}
if(toInsert.size() > 0) insert toInsert;
}
```

But when I test it, I'm getting `null` value instead of correct `MoreInfo__c`.

What is wrong here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Now you have a SOQL inside a for loop which is against best practices since for every record affected by the trigger you will repeat the query, this of course will cause you to reach very easily the governor limits.

Comment: But I took it out of the cycle. The code is below the first. But what is wrong again? How to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the places. Changed.

Comment: The issue is that you are doing the query before you have put the data into the list you're checking to obtain the records. But it would be helpful if you edited the question and explain your use case so we can understand better what are you trying to achieve and help you better to understand what is wrong with the current logic.

Comment: Thank you, Alexander. I changed my question.

Comment: I just can't understand why I'm getting `null` with the query outside the `for` loop.

Comment: N.B. `if(toInsert.size() > 0)` is not necessary; SFDC will happily do nothing when the list of sobjects is empty and not burn a DML limits call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your code is right now, `moreInfo` is an empty List, so you shouldn't be getting any results:

```
List<String> moreInfo = new List<String>();   // <=== EMPTY right now!
List<Detail__c> details = [SELECT Info__c FROM Detail__c
                                WHERE MoreInfo__c IN : moreInfo LIMIT 1];
```

Use your `for` loop before the `details` SOQL query:

```
List<String> moreInfo = new List<String>();
for(Tool__c tool : Trigger.new){
    moreInfo.add(tool.MoreInfo__c);
}

List<Detail__c> details = [SELECT Info__c FROM Detail__c
                                WHERE MoreInfo__c IN : moreInfo]; // NOW getting results
```

You'll still want to map out each detail to it's `MoreInfo__c` lookup field, so that you're pulling the right data for each `tool`

Comment: Hm. So I'll get just the last element from the end of loop in my `moreInfo` list? I can get through import 100 or 200 records... And how can I get `Gear__c gear = new Gear__c(Tool__c = tool.Id);` - the `tool.Id` value too?

Comment: The point is I can have many importing `Tools`. For each of these records I have to create and insert a new `Gear__c` with correct fields (all fields are tied to inserting records).

Comment: @Apelsinova Your interpretation isn't quite right. The first loop over your `Tools`, using `Trigger.new` to feed it. Each iteration of the first loop adds a value to the `moreInfo` list, so if your trigger is working on 200 records, you'll get all 200 values of `MoreInfo__c` in that `moreInfo` list (including any duplicates). As for your other question (how to get `tool.Id` for your `Gear__c` records), well, you said that `MoreInfo__c` is related to `Tool__c`, so what's stopping you from adding that to your `details` query?